# Validation onclick button is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm currently getting error `"[b.reportValidity is not a function]"`

Below is the code:

HTML:

```
<lightning-combobox required name="duration" label="Select Duration" value={durationValue} placeholder="Select Duration" options={durationOptions}></lightning-combobox>
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Generate" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

JS:

```
handleClick(event) {
    const allValid = [this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox')]
        .reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) = > {
            inputCmp.reportValidity();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
        }, true);
    if (allValid) {
        alert('All form entries look valid. Ready to submit!');
    } else {
        alert('Please update the invalid form entries and try again.');
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change code like below and it will work. There is small change in code at `...this.template.querySelectorAll`

```
handleClick(event) {

    const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox')]
        .reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
            inputCmp.reportValidity();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
        }, true);
    if (allValid) {
        alert('All form entries look valid. Ready to submit!');
    } else {
        alert('Please update the invalid form entries and try again.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is working fine but could you explain why '...' is required?

Comment: It is called spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments. Check link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax for more detail.